# Are non-zero paddings used?

Tags: convolutional-neural-network

I currently tried to figure out which paddings are directly supported by the frameworks:

Tensorflow ([`tf.nn.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv2d)):

- `padding='VALID'`: No padding
- `padding='SAME'`: 0-padding such that the output has the same size as the input

By applying [`tf.pad`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#pad) and then `padding='VALID'` one can get reflect and symmetric padding.

Lasagne ([`lasagne.layers.Conv2DLayer`](http://lasagne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/layers/conv.html#lasagne.layers.Conv2DLayer)) (and probably also Theano):

- `pad='full'`: A variant of 0-padding which results in a bigger image
- `pad='same'`: Like `SAME` for TF
- `pad='valid'`: Like `SAME` for TF

Caffe ([docs](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html)): I have no idea which padding they support. As `pad_h` and `pad_w` seem to be in `convolution_param`, I guess padding is supported. Probably (only?) zero-padding.

Hence my question:

**Are there publications where CNNs with padding, which was neither `VALID` nor `SAME`, or not 0-padding, was used?**

For example, I know of the following other options:

- reflect
- nearest

both of them might have the advantage, that the filter does not detect a border, where no border is.